# Changing attribute value for a pseudo-CSS class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

So, I've been trying to find an easy and simple way to access a pseudo CSS class via JavaScript/jQuery but it seems that isn't possible due to those parts not specifically being on the DOM. Essentially, I need help programmatically changing the `background` value in the following snippet:

```
.navbar .link::after {
   content: '';
   display: block;
   margin-top: -13px;
   width: 0;
   height: 5px;
   background: #ffffff;
   transition: width .3s;
}
```

I was trying to do `$('.link::after').css('background','gold');` but that did not work. How can I tackle this?

Also, [here's](https://jsfiddle.net/oax0vqs2/) the fiddle.

Comment: how about you define a new class with desired background and attach it to your `.link` element when needed?

Comment: @ZoltanToth Wow I can't believe I didn't realize that. Thank you so much!